# Change activity type of a *.fit file

Tags: gps, garmin, strava

Is there some software doing this ?
No, I don't mean changing the type of an already imported 'workout' from service level. A 'service' being Strava, TrainingPeaks, Garmin Connect, etc.

#### Motivation

I'm using Garmin Connect's AutoSync to sync my workouts to bunch of services.
I would like to alter activity type (say: Ride→Run) of a fit file prior to  uploading to Garmin Connect, so I won't have to visit all the services and change the bloody activity type.

(I'm using Garmin Edge to track my runs too. It records every single activity as a 'Ride'.
I'm a cyclist running only occasionally, so no, I am not buying a running-dedicated device.)

---

Quick googling says, that writing a script doing this is doable in, like, 40min of time.
But maybe that would be reinventing the wheel.

Should be included in [FitFileTools](https://www.fitfiletools.com/#/) IMO.

Comment: It's well worth a look, though I don't know of anything. I got half way through writing a script to modify gpx files only to Google a detail and find a website that did what I wanted. There are lots of people out there modifying these things.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems as though it should be on the super user or some other more software centric site.

Comment: When you make a change on Connect, doesn't the update carry through to the other services?

Comment: close-vote: You, Sir, are wrong. Yes, I considered asking it on [GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com) and [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). I think it's more appropriate here as more cyclists can face the very same problem. 
Super-user? I'm not asking (yet) how to implement this. I'm looking for a ready solution.

Comment: changing on Connect: No, it doesn't propagate the change to other services.

Comment: Voting to leave open because its still bike stuff.   This would be no use without a bike.

Comment: If you have an editor that can view binary data, like emacs, there should be two instances of the activity type in the file, padded by null characters (looks like `^@` in emacs). Just replace the two instances of the old activity type with the new, and make sure to remove extra null characters if the new activity type is longer, or add extra ones (copy/paste is easiest way to do this) if it is shorter.